# Involve or Involved?

Tags: tense

In this sentence, would I use the word "involve" or "involved", and what is a way to be able to tell which is the correct usage in a sentence?

> There is a wide variety of careers that **involve** diving in not only oceans but also aquariums, rivers, lakes, ponds, and even water tanks.

OR

> There is a wide variety of careers that **involved** diving in not only oceans but also aquariums, rivers, lakes, ponds, and even water tanks.

Answer (score 3):

As always, grammar is the servant of meaning. What do you want your audience to understand?

If you want it to understand that at some time in the past there were such careers, you might say

> There used to be careers that involved diving ...

All verbs in a past tense.

If you want your audience to understand that careers currently involving that activity exist today, you might say

> There are careers that involve diving ...

All verbs in a present tense.

If you want your audience to understand that careers exist currently that once involved diving but no longer do so, you might say

> There are [still] careers that used to involve diving ...

A verb in the present tense involving careers and a verb in the past tense involving diving. Although subtle differences in meaning can be implied by tense alone, the normal practice in English is to supplement tense with additional words such as "still" whenever a subtlety is intended.